# Get user authentication before next UI View will appear

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, segue, completionhandler

I am working on user authentication process but i stuck in the moment when reciving data from rest with token. Whenever i create the new task it does not enter on the first time into the function but after creating it skipping doing smth else which is showing a next hooked up `UIViewController` to segue.

My rest service with post method hashing user password, creating json, URL request and at the end creating `URLSession`. How could i wait for finish of this task ? To not let to do anything else before it is not complited ?

### EDIT

I've added `OpeartionQueue` to liquidate nil's from next view.

```
func postLogin(name:String, pass:String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> () ) {
            let md5Data = self.MD5(string:pass)
            let hashPass = md5Data!.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
            let json: [String: Any] = ["username": name,
                                       "passwordHash": hashPass ]

            let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

            // create post request
            let url = URL(string: LOGIN_URL)!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            // insert json data to the request
            request.httpBody = jsonData
            request.setValue("application/json;charest=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                    return
                }
                let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                    print(responseJSON)
                    let message:String = responseJSON["message"] as! String
                    if !(message.range(of: "ERROR") != nil){
                        SessionMenager.Instance.token = message
                        completion(true)
                    }
                } else{
                    print(error.debugDescription)

                }
            }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Then simply in my `LoginViewController` action with button :

```
  @IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: Any) {

   let username = usernameTextField.text
    let password = passwordTextField.text

    if username == "" {
        AlertWindow(title: "Username", message: "Wrong username")
    } else if password == "" {
        AlertWindow(title: "Password", message: "Wrong password")
    } else {
        let usernameToUpper = username!.uppercased()
        RestService.Instance.postLogin(name: usernameToUpper, pass: password!, completion: { sth in
            if sth {
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    [weak self] in
                    self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mapSegue", sender: self)
                }
            } else {
                return
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The segue was hooked up into `LoginButton` which took me instantly to the next page. I've changed it into hooking up all view controllerr.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your segue is hooked up into LoginButton, it will automatically show the next viewController once you press the button.
Just hoop up the segue to the whole viewController and it should work.

Comment: Yeah. I did it few minutes ago - realized how exsactly it works. Also i have to update code becosue i had to add `OperationQueue`